# Command line option to check if another user is connected to the system

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares

I know how to find it out by GUI, but I need to check this in cmd in batch script. Basically I need to find out if connection on PC is shared to some other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Command line option to check if another user is connected to the system?**

Perhaps the [`net session`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490711.aspx) command?

---

Update:

> **I need to find out if sharing network is enabled on windows in general**

To view what is shared by a specific computer

```
net view \\computername
```

For example

```
C:\> net view \\BUBBA
Shared resources at \\BUBBA

bubba Miniserver

Share name  Type  Used as  Comment

-----------------------------------------------
home        Disk           Home Directories
storage     Disk           Common storage
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: I guess it would work if someone was connected at the time, but what if no one is connected? I need to find out if sharing network is enabled on windows in general.

Comment: @tikend: see update. If you have other questions, please ask separately (and please take care with question titles).